# Mongoose Aggregate with $match on date range or local time zone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, timezone-offset

I have invoice Model as following

```
{
...

"itemDetails": [
            {
                "item":  "593a1a01bbb00000043d9a4c",
                "purchasingPrice": 100,
                "sellingPrice": 150,
                "qty": 200,
                "_id": "59c39c2a5149560004173a05",
                "discount": 0
            }
        ],
        "payments": [],
        "status": "PENDING",
        "created": {
            "$date": "2017-09-21T11:02:02.675Z"
        },
...

}
```

Sample Invoice Document is as follows.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59c39c2a5149560004173a04"
    },
    "customer": {
        "$oid": "5935013832f9fc0004fa9a16"
    },
    "order": {
        "$oid": "59c1df8393cbba0004a0e956"
    },
    "employee": {
        "$oid": "592d0a6238880f0004637e84"
    },
    "status": "PENDING",
    "deliveryStatus": "PROCESSING",
    "created": {
        "$date": "2017-09-21T11:02:02.675Z"
    },
    "discount": 0,
    "payments": [],
    "itemDetails": [
        {
            "item": {
                "$oid": "593a1a01bbb00000043d9a4c"
            },
            "purchasingPrice": 100,
            "sellingPrice": 150,
            "qty": 200,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "59c39c2a5149560004173a05"
            },
            "discount": 0
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Item details Item is an object Id which refers to Item collection.

I'm writing a mongoose Aggregate query to get the sale by Item. for that I need to filter the invoice from a given date range and `status` does not equal to "CANCELED". for that, I have written following code

```
module.exports.saleByItem = (req, res) => {
  let fromDate;
  let toDate;
  if ((req.query.fromDate && moment(req.query.fromDate, config.dateFormat, true).isValid()) && (req.query.toDate && moment(req.query.toDate, config.dateFormat, true).isValid())) {
    fromDate = moment(req.query.fromDate, config.dateFormat).startOf('day');
    toDate = moment(req.query.toDate, config.dateFormat).endOf('day');
  }
  Invoice.aggregate([
    {
      "$match": {
        "created": {
          "$gte": fromDate
            ? fromDate.toDate()
            : undefined,
          "$lte": toDate
            ? toDate.toDate()
            : undefined
        },
        "status": {
          "$ne": "CANCELED"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "$unwind": "$itemDetails"
    }, {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$itemDetails.item",
        "qty": {
          "$sum": "$itemDetails.qty"
        },
        "value": {
          "$sum": {
            "$multiply": [
              "$itemDetails.qty", {
                "$subtract": ["$itemDetails.sellingPrice", "$itemDetails.discount"]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "avarageSellingPrice": {
          "$avg": {
            "$subtract": ["$itemDetails.sellingPrice", "$itemDetails.discount"]
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      "$sort": {
        "value": -1
      }
    }, {
      "$lookup": {
        from: "items",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "item"
      }
    }, {
      "$unwind": "$item"
    }, {
      "$project": {
        _id: 1,
        itemName: "$item.itemName",
        qty: 1,
        value: 1,
        avarageSellingPrice: 1
      }
    }
  ]).then(salesFigures => {
    res.status(200).json(salesFigures);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(422).json(err);
  });
};
```

The issue is when I put today date to both dates it returns sale of today. Gives `[]`

How to handle date ranges in $match with local time-zone?

Comment: So a couple of problems here, but most notably *"Item details Item is an object Id which refers to Item collection."* So you mean Your `Invoice` model actually has an "array" of `ObjectId` like `{ "itemDetails": [ObjectId("59f81147e1fd20702029129a"), ObjectId("59f81153e1fd20702029129b")] }` right? Or at the very least it's an array of "objects", but you seem to be implying the former.

Comment: @NeilLunn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904383/mongoose-aggregate-with-lookup-with-group as in here it works. i have issue in match part

Comment: Which is supposed to mean what? I asked you a yes or no question. Your question here makes no mention of `$lookup`. So if this is not your actual aggregation pipeline then you best update your question. At the very least the "body" of your question disagrees with the data presented in the question.

Comment: @NeilLunn add full implementation

Comment: You still did not answer, but it does actually appear "embedded" to some extent. Which means `"created"` and `"status"` are actually **inside** the `itemDetails` array. So `{ "$match": { "itemDetails": { "$elemMatch": { "created": { "$gte": fromDate.toDate(), "$lte": toDate.toDate() }, "status": { "$ne": "CANCELLED"  } } } }`. But that's just "document selection". If you are expecting to "filter the arrays" then you also need to do that. Either after `$unwind` or using `$filter` beforehand.

Comment: @NeilLunn added sample document from Invoice Collection